# Error: Invalid column name 'B'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to create a simple registration page with ASP.NET C# in Visual Studio 2013.

I've encountered the following error upon clicking on the submit button to ensure that the registration details get into the database that I've tried to connect to.

> Error:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'B'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at Registration.submitButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Desktop\IIPWebsite\Registration.aspx.cs:line 56 ClientConnectionId:41bb1e5f-3298-4b70-89d6-b12d0519ea55

My code for the aspx page are as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Registration.aspx.cs" Inherits="Registration" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <title>NHH Consultants</title>
     <meta name="keywords" content="" />
     <meta name="description" content="" />
     <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900" rel="stylesheet" />
     <link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
     <link href="fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
     <!--[if IE 6]>
     < link href="default_ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <![endif]-->
     <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        .style3
        {
            font-size: 4em;
        }
        .style4
        {
            width: 208px;
        }
        .style2
        {
            width: 126px;
        }
        .style6
        {
            font-size: medium;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }
        .style7
        {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 30pt;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }
        .style8
        {
            color: #FF9933;
        }
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 261px;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 126px;
            height: 27px;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            width: 208px;
            height: 27px;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            width: 261px;
            height: 27px;
        }
        .auto-style12 {
            width: 152px;
            height: 26px;
        }
        .auto-style14 {
            width: 261px;
            height: 26px;
        }
        .auto-style23 {
            width: 152px;
            height: 29px;
        }
        .auto-style25 {
            width: 261px;
            height: 29px;
        }
        .auto-style26 {
            width: 206px;
        }
        .auto-style27 {
            width: 206px;
            height: 26px;
        }
        .auto-style28 {
            width: 206px;
            height: 29px;
        }
        .auto-style29 {
            font-size: medium;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            width: 152px;
        }
        .auto-style30 {
            width: 152px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" runat="server">
<div id="header-wrapper" 
        style="background-image: url('images/NYC_Night.jpg')">
    <div id="header-wrapper2">
        <div id="header" class="container">
            <div id="logo">
                <h1 style="color: #FFFFFF">NHH Consultants</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#" accesskey="1" title="">Homepage</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" accesskey="2" title="">LOGIN</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" accesskey="3" title="">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" accesskey="4" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" accesskey="4" title="">Services</a></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="major">
            <h2 class="style3">reliability, Anytime, anywhere</h2>
            <span class="style1">Your number one electrical &amp; mechanical engineering 
            consultant</span>&nbsp; </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper1" class="style7">
    <strong>Registration 
    <br />
    &quot;*&quot; Denotes field is compulsory</strong></div>
    <table class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style29">
                *Username:</td>
            <td class="style4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="userTB" runat="server" Width="180px">    </asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style1">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="userTB" ErrorMessage="Username is required!" 
                    ForeColor="Red" CssClass="style8"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style29">
                *Password:</td>
            <td class="style4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="passTB" runat="server" Width="180px" TextMode="Password" ViewStateMode="Disabled">   </asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style1">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="passTB" ErrorMessage="Password is required!" 
                    ForeColor="Red" CssClass="style8"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style29">
                *Confirm Password:</td>
            <td class="style4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="confirmTB" runat="server" Width="180px" TextMode="Password">   </asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style1">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="confirmTB" ErrorMessage="Confirmation of password is required!" 
                    ForeColor="Red" CssClass="style8"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <br />
                <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ControlToCompare="passTB" ControlToValidate="confirmTB" 
                    ErrorMessage="Passwords do not match!" ForeColor="Red" CssClass="style8"></asp:CompareValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style29">
                *Email:</td>
            <td class="style4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="emailTB" runat="server" Width="180px">   </asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style1">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="emailTB" ErrorMessage="Email is required!" 
                    ForeColor="Red" CssClass="style8"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <br />
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="emailTB" ErrorMessage="Email is invalid!" ForeColor="Red" 
                    ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" 
                    CssClass="style8"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style29">
                *Company name:</td>
            <td class="style4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="companyTB" runat="server" Width="180px">   </asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style1">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="companyTB" ErrorMessage="Company is required!" 
                    ForeColor="Red" CssClass="style8"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style30" style="color: #FFFFFF">
                *First name:</td>
            <td class="style4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="firstnameTB" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style1" title="First name is required!">

                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="firstnameTB" ErrorMessage="First name is required!" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style30" style="color: #FFFFFF">*Last name:</td>
                <td class="auto-style26">
                <asp:TextBox ID="lastnameTB" runat="server" Width="179px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Last name is required!" ControlToValidate="lastnameTB" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style12" style="color: #FFFFFF">*Address:</td>
                <td class="auto-style27">
                <asp:TextBox ID="addressTB" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style14">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Address is required!" ControlToValidate="addressTB" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style30" style="color: #FFFFFF">*Postal Code:</td>
                <td class="auto-style26">
                <asp:TextBox ID="postalcodeTB" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Postal Code is required!" ControlToValidate="postalcodeTB" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <br />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="postalcodeTB" ErrorMessage="Postal code is invalid!" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\d{6}(\d{4})?$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style12" style="color: #FFFFFF">*Contact Number:</td>
                <td class="auto-style27">
                <asp:TextBox ID="contactnumberTB" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style14">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Contact number is required!" ControlToValidate="contactnumberTB" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <br />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="contactnumberTB" ErrorMessage="Contact number is invalid!" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^[689]\d{7}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style23" style="color: #FFFFFF">
                    <br />
                    Date of Birth:</td>
                <td class="auto-style28" style="color: Red">
                    <asp:Label ID="dateLabel" runat="server" ForeColor="#FFFF66" Text="Date in YYYY-MM-DD format" Visible="True"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="dateTB" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style25" style="color: Red">
                    <br />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dateTB" ErrorMessage="Date is invalid!" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style30" style="color: #FFFFFF">City:</td>
                <td class="auto-style26">
                <asp:TextBox ID="cityTB" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style30" style="color: #FFFFFF">Fax number:</td>
                <td class="auto-style26">
                <asp:TextBox ID="faxTB" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style30">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style26">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                </td>
            <td class="auto-style3">
                </td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <asp:Button ID="submitButton" runat="server" onclick="submitButton_Click" 
                    Text="Submit" Height="23px" Width="97px" />
                <asp:Button ID="resetButton" runat="server" onclick="resetButton_Click" Text="Reset fields" Height="23px" Width="97px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

While my codes for the aspx.cs page are as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisterConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string checkuser = "select count(*) from Client where cUserName= '" + userTB.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

            if (temp == 1)
            {
                Response.Write("Username is already taken! Please choose another username.");
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisterConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string insertQuery = "insert into Client (cFirstName, cLastName, cD.O.B, cCompanyName, cAddress, cCity, cZipCode, cPhoneNo, cFax, cEmail, cUsername, cPassword) values (@firstname,@lastname,@dob,@companyname,@address,@city,@zipcode,@phoneno,@fax,@email,@username,@password)";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstnameTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lastnameTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dateTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyname", companyTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", addressTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", cityTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zipcode", postalcodeTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phoneno", contactnumberTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fax", faxTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passTB.Text);

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("Congratulations! Your registration is successful!");
            Response.Redirect("ClientLogin.aspx");

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    protected void resetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Registration.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to insert data into a field called *c.D.O.B.* in the database. Wrap it in square brackets and things should work, i.e.

```
insert into Client (cFirstName, cLastName, [cD.O.B], ...
```

If you have any influence on the database design, make sure to change that column name into something a little more sensible. Periods in column names don't play well with a lot of tooling, and have very little added value here.

Comment: @SarahCollins Mark it as answer if the post has helped you.